# Netbeans not reading .jnilib file

Tags: java, macos, netbeans

I have a project on netbeans that I am trying to run on my mac. The problem is every time it gets to the line:

```
System.load(libPath + File.separatorChar + "libjdic.jnilib");
```

It gives me the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: {path}/libjdic.jnilib:  no suitable image found.  Did find:  {path}/libjdic.jnilib: no matching architecture in universal wrapper
>
> ```
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1827)
>    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1703)
>    at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:770)
>    at java.lang.System.load(System.java:1020)
>    at ------.-------App.main(--------App.java:113)
> ```
>
> Java Result: 1

I have checked, and the paths are all correct. This is working on windows, but I need it to work on mac as well. It is properly determining the OS and deciding which additional files to load (In this case `.jnilib`). I have seen a similar question on here, but without an answer.

SPECS:

Mac OSX 10.8.4

64bit

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_45-b06-451-11M4406)

Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.45-b01-451, mixed mode)

Netbeans version 7.3.1

Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: `java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError` Means that java can't find the library file, check if the file path is right, if it's not, then update it and try again

Comment: "I have checked, and the paths are all correct." I have done a clean and build to ensure that I didn't mess something up, and it still does not work. While looking at the file again, I did notice that it is a 32 bit file. Would this cause the issue? BTW thanks for the formatting corrections. I have not seen a link to anything explaining what the standards are for that. If you could add one, that would be great. If there isn't one, you should make one because it would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, a 32-bit library is also a problem, because 64-bit jvm can't load 32-bit libraries. BTW, with windows and linux if you had this error you would have ended up with a `IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit`, maybe that on Mac OSX it's different, so try downloading (or compiling, if you have the source code) the library with 64bit target and try loading it again

Comment: I actually don't have the source code. The files that I need are libtray.jnilib (library for tray notifications) and libjdic.jnilib. If anyone knows where I can get the 64-bit versions of these, please let me know.